# iFunbox App Install Failed (-402620395)

Tags: iphone, ios

I created Ad Hoc distribution profile for beta testing my app by adding the test devices. I installed the app in one of my iPhone4 using iFunbox that runs good, but when i try to install in iPhone 5 it says

`iFunbox App Install Failed (-402620395)`

Am not sure what causes this error and how to resolve it. If i can run a app in iPhone 4 using iFunbox why not on iPhone 5 using the same iFunbox.

Can anyone suggest an idea.

Comment: Why are you installing with iFunBox? What is wrong with Xcode / iTunes?

Comment: @Wain one of my client uses windows OS where he is trying to install using iFunbox and getting failed with the error

Comment: iTunes is still the more reliable method.

Comment: Wain, iFunBox is much more functional than iTunes, which is impossible to use on Windows. Besides, it is better for jailbreaking!

Answer (score 5):

For an AdHoc distribution -- that's a provisioning error.

Go to Apple developer center and verify that the iPhone 5 is a added to the AdHoc provisioning profile.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Comment: You mean adding UDID for iPhone 5? I had already added the UDID for iPhone 5 in Devices section in my developer account

Comment: Yep.  Personally, I'd double check everything with the device that's causing a problem.